# Pandas agg how to count rows where a condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

I am using lambda function and agg() in python to perform some function on each element of the dataframe.

I have following cases

1. lambda x: (x==0).sum() - Question: Does this logically compute (x==0) as 1, if true, and 0, if false and then adds all ones and zeros? or is it doing something else?
2. lambda x: x.sum() - Question: This is apparent, but still I'll ask. This adds all the elements or x passed to it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

`(x == 0).sum()` counts the number of rows where the condition `x == 0` is true. `x.sum()` just computes the "sum" of `x` (the actual result depends on the type).

Comment: So it is correct to say that (x == 0) will return 1 or 0 and then sum(), in a way computes the number of rows.

Comment: @cs95 thank you for this. Do you know why it is (x == 0).sum() and not (x == 0).count()? I cannot see why .count() should not work, yet it does not work when I use it in this context.

Comment: @DarceyBM count calls all non-null values, which can be both the count of true and false. sum() only adds the numeric values, assigning 1 to True and 0 to False, effectively telling you how many rows are true. Semantically different meanings